# Update column in KDB table based on condition of multiple columns in table

Tags: kdb

When all columns (d1;d4) = "NC" for each pair I am looking to update adjustment to "NO ADJ"

In the below case only the first row satisfies the condition and should be updated

```
t:flip (`pair`d1`d2`d3`d4`vol`adjustment)!(`pair1`pair2`pair3`pair4;("NC";"3/-0.09";"1/-0.09";"NC");("NC";"4/-0.09";"-1/-0.09";"NC");("NC";"2/-0.09";"1/0.09";"2/0.3");("NC";"4/-0.09";"0/-0.09";"NC");0 89.68 78.3 0;("0.1bp";"0.1bp";"0.1bp";"0.1bp"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

While Eliot's answer is perfectly correct for the question at face value. If you have many columns of name like "d*" then you can generalise to this form and it will check all columns (d1,d2,...,dn) for "NC".

`` ![`t;{(like;x;"NC")}each ((cols t) where (cols t) like "d*");0b;(enlist `adjustment)!enlist (enlist;"NO ADJ")] ``

What this update does is take each column like "d*" and if all columns are "NC" it will change adjustment to "NO ADJ" as requested.

This update statement can be modified as necessary for different column groups.

Edit: As Dunny's comment suggests, having `t at ![`t;... will do the change in place. If you would like to test and see what it looks like without changing the table in memory then changing `t to t would work for that purpose

Comment: white paper to show how to convert from q-sql (update/select/delete/exec) to functional form (the query shown here). https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/#functional-queries

Definitely the most flexible and scalable answer

Comment: Good to note aswell the backtick before the t causes the change to be made to the variable in memory

Answer (score 1):

This update statement will do what you need:

```
update adjustment:enlist"NO ADJ" from t where all(d1;d2;d3;d4)~\:\:"NC"
```

Two each-lefts are needed since `(d1;...;d4)` is a list of list of strings. The result of this comparison is

```
q)(t`d1;t`d2;t`d3;t`d4)~\:\:"NC"
1001b
1001b
1000b
1001b
```

then applying the `all` keyword will "squash" these booleans into one list:

```
q)all(t`d1;t`d2;t`d3;t`d4)~\:\:"NC"
1000b
```

Finally, you need to use `enlist` on the string `"NO ADJ"`, otherwise there will be a length error due to kdb trying to update the adjustement column pairwise for each character in the string `"NO ADJ"`.

Answer (score 1):

This should provide the solution for the data you provided. You need to use each left to apply the where clause across all columns. This will leave you with a list of  4 booleans of where the condition is met within each row. This is why we then use the all keyword aswell to ensure we only update the result which matches every column.

```
q)update adjustment:enlist"NO ADJ" from t where all (d1;d2;d3;d4) like\:"NC"
pair  d1        d2         d3        d4        vol   adjustment
---------------------------------------------------------------
pair1 "NC"      "NC"       "NC"      "NC"      0     "NO ADJ"
pair2 "3/-0.09" "4/-0.09"  "2/-0.09" "4/-0.09" 89.68 "0.1bp"
pair3 "1/-0.09" "-1/-0.09" "1/0.09"  "0/-0.09" 78.3  "0.1bp"
pair4 "NC"      "NC"       "2/0.3"   "NC"      0     "0.1bp"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this

```
q)t
pair  d1        d2         d3        d4        vol   adjustment
---------------------------------------------------------------
pair1 "NC"      "NC"       "NC"      "NC"      0     "0.1bp"
pair2 "3/-0.09" "4/-0.09"  "2/-0.09" "4/-0.09" 89.68 "0.1bp"
pair3 "1/-0.09" "-1/-0.09" "1/0.09"  "0/-0.09" 78.3  "0.1bp"
pair4 "NC"      "NC"       "2/0.3"   "NC"      0     "0.1bp"
q)update adjustment:enlist"NO ADJ" from t where([]d1;d2;d3;d4)~\:`d1`d2`d3`d4!4#enlist"NC"
pair  d1        d2         d3        d4        vol   adjustment
---------------------------------------------------------------
pair1 "NC"      "NC"       "NC"      "NC"      0     "NO ADJ"
pair2 "3/-0.09" "4/-0.09"  "2/-0.09" "4/-0.09" 89.68 "0.1bp"
pair3 "1/-0.09" "-1/-0.09" "1/0.09"  "0/-0.09" 78.3  "0.1bp"
pair4 "NC"      "NC"       "2/0.3"   "NC"      0     "0.1bp"
```

This works by first creating an intermediary dictionary

```
q)`d1`d2`d3`d4!4#enlist"NC"
d1| "NC"
d2| "NC"
d3| "NC"
d4| "NC"
```

and then checking is each element of the table `([]d1;d2;d3;d4)` exactly equal to this dictionary

e.g similar to constructs like

`1 2 3~\:1`

In this case we're using the fact that all a table is is a list of dictionaries and, with some lateral thinking, we can often find ways to exploit this fact

Answer (score 1):

So far **all of currently suggested solutions fail in the case of multiple replacements**

```
q)t:100000 # flip (`pair`d1`d2`d3`d4`vol`adjustment)!(`pair1`pair2`pair3`pair4;("NC";"3/-0.09";"1/-0.09";"NC");("NC";"4/-0.09";"-1/-0.09";"NC");("NC";"2/-0.09";"1/0.09";"2/0.3");("NC";"4/-0.09";"0/-0.09";"NC");0 89.68 78.3 0;("0.1bp";"0.1bp";"0.1bp";"0.1bp"))
q)update adjustment:enlist"NO ADJ" from t where all(d1;d2;d3;d4)~\:\:"NC"
'length
  [0]  update adjustment:enlist"NO ADJ" from t where all(d1;d2;d3;d4)~\:\:"NC"
       ^
q)update adjustment:enlist"NO ADJ" from t where all (d1;d2;d3;d4) like\:"NC"
'length
  [0]  update adjustment:enlist"NO ADJ" from t where all (d1;d2;d3;d4) like\:"NC"

q)![`t;{(like;x;"NC")}each ((cols t) where (cols t) like "d*");0b;(enlist `adjustment)!enlist (enlist;"NO ADJ")]
'length
  [0]  ![`t;{(like;x;"NC")}each ((cols t) where (cols t) like "d*");0b;(enlist `adjustment)!enlist (enlist;"NO ADJ")]
       ^
```

This is because there is no easy way to determine the number of "NO ADJ" strings you need to substitute in.

```
'length
  [0]  update adjustment:enlist "adfjkl" from t where i in 1 2 3
                                                           ^
q)update adjustment:3#enlist "adfjkl" from t where i in 1 2 3
pair  d1        d2         d3        d4        vol   adjustment
---------------------------------------------------------------
pair1 "NC"      "NC"       "NC"      "NC"      0     "0.1bp"
pair2 "3/-0.09" "4/-0.09"  "2/-0.09" "4/-0.09" 89.68 "adfjkl"
pair3 "1/-0.09" "-1/-0.09" "1/0.09"  "0/-0.09" 78.3  "adfjkl"
pair4 "NC"      "NC"       "2/0.3"   "NC"      0     "adfjkl"
pair1 "NC"      "NC"       "NC"      "NC"      0     "0.1bp"
```

The best way to handle this type of vector replacment is through a [vector conditional](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/vector-conditional/)

```
q)update adjustment:?[&/[{"NC" ~/:x} each (d1;d2;d3;d4)];(count adjustment)#enlist "NO ADJ";adjustment] from t
pair  d1        d2         d3        d4        vol   adjustment
---------------------------------------------------------------
pair1 "NC"      "NC"       "NC"      "NC"      0     "NO ADJ"
pair2 "3/-0.09" "4/-0.09"  "2/-0.09" "4/-0.09" 89.68 "0.1bp"
pair3 "1/-0.09" "-1/-0.09" "1/0.09"  "0/-0.09" 78.3  "0.1bp"
pair4 "NC"      "NC"       "2/0.3"   "NC"      0     "0.1bp"
pair1 "NC"      "NC"       "NC"      "NC"      0     "NO ADJ"
```

The performance of this will also generally be excellent.

Examining my conditional

```
?[&/[{"NC" ~/:x} each (d1;d2;d3;d4)];(count adjustment)#enlist "NO ADJ";adjustment]
```

In my where clause, `{"NC" ~/:x} each (d1;d2;d3;d4)` produces 4 vector boolean lists, I then collapse them with `&` (and) and the [converge operation](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/accumulators/#converge), to get where all conditions are true.

The other two components are my replacement vectors, **they must be of equal length**. This condition avoids the pitfalls of the other two attempts where you cannot know the number of replacements required.